# Rails 3.2: Serialize a collection of ActiveRecord objects to JSON with a single root element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

How do I get a collection of ActiveRecords to serialize to a JSON object with a single root element that contains an array of the colletions elements?

We just upgraded from Rails 3.0.10 to Rails 3.2 and running into problems with the way collections of ActiveRecord objects are serialized to JSON.

I've done some reading and know that using `to_json` the way we are is probably a bad idea and we'll look to fix that soon but in the interim, I'm looking for the fastest way way possible to fix my code so it does what it did before as these changes broke our API.

We have a collection ActiveRecord objects of type Form that were being returned in an "index" action as JSON using the following code:

```
def index # in our FormsController

  # get our "records" collection from the database

  respond_to do |format|
    yield(format) if block_given?

    # other formats excluded for simplicity

    format.json {
      records = records.call if records.is_a?(Proc)
      render :json => records.to_json(serialize_records_options), :layout => false
    }
  end
end

# These are in ApplicationController

def serialize_options
  (self.class.serialize_options if self.class.respond_to? :serialize_options) || {}
end

def serialize_records_options
  options = serialize_options.clone
  options[:root] = (options[:root].pluralize if options[:root]) || controller_name
  options[:indent] ||= 2
  options
end
```

The problem is that this used to serialize as:

```
{
    "total_entries": 2,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "forms": [{
        "form": {
            ... attributes ...
        }
    },
    {
        "form": {
            ... attributes ...
        }
    }],
    "per_page": 5,
    "current_page": 1
}
```

and now serializes as:

```
[{
  "forms": { 
    ... attributes of form 1 ... 
  }
},
{
  "forms": { 
    ... attributes of form 2 ... 
  }
},
{
... more forms ...
}]
```

Our client apps are not recognizing that format as even being a valid JSON object. Any ideas on how we can get it to output in the original format? We haven't changed any of our serialization code other than upgrading Rails and it's dependencies. We have the following JSON gems in our bundle:

```
$ bundle show | grep json
  * json (1.7.3)
  * jsonpath (0.5.0)
  * multi_json (1.3.5)
```

Thanks in advance! This is a weird one.

Comment: I guess `to_json` isnt required I guess `:json =>` would convert it to json object

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that, but it still is not solving our problem of being able to output the collection as a JSON object with a single root element.

Comment: could please share your json response

Comment: I included it above. You can see what the response used to look like and what it looks like now. The big difference is that the whole collection was in a JSON object with a root element 'forms'.

Comment: JFI did you set `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true`

Comment: I tried putting: `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true` in my config/environment.rb but it didn't seem to make a difference. Does it belong somewhere else?

Comment: Ok Just put it before your render statement and you can decide on the placement later on

Comment: No dice. It's still returning an array of JSON objects where each object has a single key 'forms' with the associated form, rather than a single JSON object with a key 'forms' that points to an array of JSON objects.

Comment: Hmmmm closely inspecting the json and your post you mention `The problem is that this used to serialize as` did actually you mean the previously it use the generate the json you expected . and now it is not . Looking at the to_json in the api `http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json` I could not find the the way to generate json the way you need perhap you should try `jbuilder` or `rabl` for that matter

Comment: I updated the issue description. Yes, in Rails 3.0.10 it used to serialize one way (which I've included) and now serializes another. The other thing I'm noticing though is the difference in pagination params.

Comment: I guess you need to customize your json creation I guess ActiveRecord does not add root element to collections of object the way you are looking for checkout Rabl or jbuilder hope that help

Comment: We also upgraded from an older will_paginate vendor/plugins plugin to [this will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)

Comment: what does that has to do with the required json what wrong with the will_paginate

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with the way will_paginate is serializing to json.